# バッジ「みんなが選んだ」の条件

Tags: サポート, バッジ

バッジ [みんなが選んだ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/populist) は

> 承認された回答を超える最高スコアを獲得し、それがスコア 10 より大きく、2 倍以上だった.

と説明されていますが、該当者はいません。例えば[longの飽和演算を行うアルゴリズムを教えてください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/10691/4236)における私の回答は該当しないのでしょうか？ 承認された回答はスコア1であり、私の回答はスコア17となっています。
もしくは説明されていない条件があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

説明されていない条件もありますが、それ以前に元々の英文が分かりにくく、和訳もミスリーディングなものになってしまったようです。Meta Stack Exchange に投稿されている ["What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?" の回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/341401)から翻訳すると、「みんなが選んだ」(Populist) の正確な条件は以下の通りです。

> - 金バッジ。何回も受賞できる。
> - 以下の条件を全て満たす回答を投稿する ([出典](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6886)):
>
>   - その質問において最も高いスコアの回答である ([出典](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6938))
>   - 承認のチェックマークがついて**いない**
>   - スコアが 23 以上である
>   - 承認された回答のスコアの 2 倍よりもひとつ以上大きいスコアである
>   - 承認された回答のスコアは 11 以上である
>   - 自己回答ではない ([出典](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119221))

「みんなが選んだ」の原文は以下の通りです。

> Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

ここで "with score of more than 10" は "an accepted answer" を修飾しているものの、"by more than 2x" は "outscored" を修飾することが意図されていたようです。正直これはバッジの実際の挙動を知らないと和訳しにくいです。逆にこの解釈を知っていれば、上に書いた正確な条件のうち「自己回答ではない」以外はこの文で説明できています。

Meta Stack Exchange には他にも「『みんなが選んだ』の説明文が分かりにくいから直そう」という提案があるものの、そのままにされていました。

### 追記

このバッジの説明文は Traducir に載っているようだったので、修正案を出してみました。

https://ja.traducir.win/string/6849

Comment: ありがとうございます。それにしても翻訳内容と条件がまったく異なりますね…。

Comment: @sayuri さん、調べてみたところ、元々の英文の時点で分かりにくいものだったので、そのことを説明した上で翻訳案を投げてみました。